# Content of popup.html in Chrome extension is not getting updated quickly

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get the background.js of my Chrome extension to update the text in a div of the popup every time it completes a task, to let the user know what's going on. I have this code in background.js:

```
...
sendStatusUpdate('Getting stuff...');
var gotStuff = getStuff();
...
sendStatusUpdate('Done.');
```

where:

```
function sendStatusUpdate(statusUpdate) {
  var views = chrome.extension.getViews({
    type: "popup"
  });
  views[0].document.getElementById('status').textContent = statusUpdate;
};
```

I expect the span to show "Getting stuff..." until the `getStuff()` function is done execution (it takes a while). But right now I'm seeing nothing until everything is done, at which point I see "Getting stuff..." flash by for a tenth of a second and then "Done." I also making background.js send a message to popup.js so that this component could update its own view, but same problem. Curiously, if I put a breakpoint after the first `sendStatusUpdate()` it stays blank until I put my mouse over or click the popup. Then it shows "Getting stuff..." no problem.

What is happening here?

Comment: All of the extension's views (that is those that start with the same chrome-extension://id URL origin) are executed in the same physical system process so if your `getStuff()` is *synchronous* it'll run before Chrome is able to update DOM of the popup. You'll have to make it async via setTimeout, for example.

Comment: ...or try [forcing the layout](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a).